# Sending product attributes/variations to client with WooCommerce API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product that is a variable product with multiple different sizes: Small, Medium, Large, X-Large, XX-Large. I'm confused as to how WooCommerce stores these attributes in the database and links them to a product. Could someone explain the WooCommerce taxonomy to me as to how it knows that these product variations/attributes belong to a specific product? I've got a product ID with the ID of 370, and can't figure out how it links the sizes to that product. Thanks.

Comment: its the other way around, the post is linked to the taxonomy, same as all taxonomies. Look into the db at post meta table, taxonomy etc you will see a lot of what you are looking for.

Comment: I did look at that, but I couldn't figure out a way that it all relates back to the product...

Comment: wp term relationships contains the post number and the term id.